# M-x org-beamer-export-to-pdf and C-c C-e l o give different results

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, beamer

The exported pdfs from `M-x org-beamer-export-to-pdf` and `C-c C-e l o` give different results. I have frames set to be created at level 1 headers (options: H1), but these headers only create frames when using `M-x org-beamer-export-to-pdf`. Using `C-c C-e l o` the level 1 headers are treated as sections. Setup below:

```
#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation]
#+OPTIONS: H:1
```

Comment: `C-c C-e l o` exports to pdf through latex. You need `C-c C-e l O` (capital O) to export to PDF through beamer.

Answer (score 1):

The latex and beamer exporters are invoked differently. If you look at the latex part of the menu after `C-c C-e`, you will see that under the `l` latex menu, you have:

> [L] as latex buffer, [l] as latex file, [p] as PDF, [o] as PDF-and-open

but

> [B] as latex buffer (beamer), [b] as latex file (beamer), [P] as PDF (beamer), [O] as PDF (beamer) and open.